# How to make a multiboot USB key?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-8.04

I want to cut my 8 GB USB key into several partitions to use [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) for a Windows XP (maybe [nLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLite_and_vLite)d before).

I also want to put the [Framakey ubuntu-fr](http://www.framakey.org/) remix pack into it such that it has the second bootable OS. I want to tweak and modify it a little because if I can I want to switch Ubuntu 9.04 to the [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) version.

How to do it easily?

IMP: in short I want to make a dual-boot USB key with Windows XP SP3 and Ubuntu 8.04.3 LTS.

Comment: I recently learned that Windows does not support multiple partitions on USB flash devices. It is likely that you will not see anything beyond the first partition in the Windows boot (maybe you won't see that too). And, I don't know what happens if your Windows boot is not on the first partition. Cannot find references at the moment, maybe someone here has more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create multiboot flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/141914/how-to-create-multiboot-flash-drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a quick and easy way to do this -

Just had a quick look at wintoflash - Can't say for XP, but for Vista and 7, you can setup the entire thing just by copying the entire dvd to your root of the usb stick.

I personally managed to install XP by copying the entire Vista dvd, then the whole Windows xp I386 folder (calling it xp_i386), on first setup screen, holding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and going to the xp_i386 folder, then running Setup along with a few switches.

Anyway, I think what you want to be looking in to is basically partitioning your 8GB flashdrive in to one small (maybe 10 or less MB) partition and set to active, then the rest to however you want.

On the small one install [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) as the bootloader, and point this to all the separate partitions. You should not have any extra problems over the normal of getting OS's to boot from USB, but GRUB on the first partition should allow you to select and choose between them all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can simply create a multiboot cd/iso image and copy it to the usb.
Either google for instructions for doing this, or use an application such as MagicISO or [USB Multiboot 10](http://www.tkshare.com/usb-multiboot-10/).

Answer (score 1):

Why not look on the easy2boot website?

Use E2B_PTN_SWAP.mnu  in your E2B menu to swap partitions

http://www.easy2boot.com/make-an-easy2boot-usb-drive/multiple-partitions-on-a-usb-flash-drive/

You can use a .mnu file to boot to Win7 direct from E2B

e.g. add

_ISO\MAINMENU\bootmgr.mnu

.................

iftitle [if exist (hd0,0)/bootmgr] Boot to Windows 7\n Boot from a partition
root (hd0,0)
chainloader /bootmgr

Other alternatives is to use one NTFS partition for both Easy2boot and Win7.

Answer (score 1):

[Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) makes multiboot USB drives. It can install both Linux and Win OS. Its windows version is more advanced than its Linux version at the moment.