# Multiboot USB solution with ISOs

Tags: boot, usb, iso-image

There are several solutions out there, but I do not know of one that works the way I want.

I want to make a multi-boot USB drive where I simply place my ISOs on it and chainload into them.  I don't want to have to partition the drive or copy files to the drive.  I simply want to place my ISOs on it, perhaps edit a menu.lst, and choose which one to boot from a menu.  When i do not need that ISO anymore I simply delete it.

Anyone know of a similar solution?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/33351/how-to-make-a-multiboot-usb-key, http://superuser.com/questions/141914/how-to-create-multiboot-flash-drive?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have been also looking.

I haven't tried this, but it looks promising.

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/multipartufd