# How to create bootable USB flash drive with more than one installation O.S.?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a multiboot USB key?](https://superuser.com/questions/33351/how-to-make-a-multiboot-usb-key)

What I want to do is to get

- Windows 7 installation (both x64 + x86)
- XP installation SP3
- HBCD

All together in 1 USB flash drive. Is there any ready to go image to download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SARDU  is a multi-boot flash drive creator that does all the hard work for you with its great GUI. Ask you have to do is put all your ISO's in one folder with a certain name for each one.

http://www.sarducd.it/

Comment: It doesn't support Windows 7 and XP SP3 isos

Comment: Are you sure about this because I have a windows 7 USB key made with SARDU. You just have to name it InstallIng.iso